# Border of angular-bootstrap popover doesn't show

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[image: Popover border missing]

I've placed it on the bottom and the border still doesn't show. I don't think it's the image that's cutting it off but it could be. Is there a way to tell the popover to show on top of the image to be sure?

Else, how do I get the border to show?

Comment: It's likely a z-index issue - inspect the z-index for the image, and also the popover, youll probably find that the popover one is lower, where it needs to be higher in the stacking order to show "above " the image.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some padding to the top of the div the popover existed in.

```
.column-ID { padding-top: 15px; }
```